# Hibernate @OnDelete cascade same table

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, cascade, cascading-deletes, hibernate-cascade

I am trying to create a table which captures parent child relationships, like a tree. I would like to maintain only two columns to capture this structure "id" and "parent". I want the database to be able to cascade delete all children when a row is deleted. Below is the Hibernate Entity that I have created, I have added the annotation `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` however, the `ON DELETE CASCADE` is not added to the table when the table is created by Hibernate.

Is this a bug? Or is there something I am missing or not understanding?

```
@Entity
public class Tree {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent", nullable = true)
    private List<Tree> children;

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent", nullable = false)
    private Tree parent;

    public Tree(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Tree() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Tree> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Tree> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public Tree getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Tree parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting `orphanRemoval=true` on the `@OneToMany` collection? (**NOT** on the `@ManyToOne`)?

Comment: Hi Pitor, I tried that, but the "ON DELETE CASCADE" is still not added to the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@OnDelete` should be used at `@OneToMany` side:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) 
private List<Tree> children;
```

Also you missed `mappedBy` - it's required in bidirectional relationships.

Comment: Thany you, that worked! I had to remove the @JoinColum annotation so that it looks like this:`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) 
private List<Tree> children;`

Comment: @Ali: Yes, `@JoinColumn` in bidirectional relationship should be placed at `@ManyToOne` side.