# OnDelete cascade fails with constraint violation error () Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
    <id name="idInstance" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="ID_INSTANCE" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>


    <property name="nom" type="string">
        <column name="NOM" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>

            <property name="description" type="string">
        <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="300" not-null="true" />
    </property>

    <set name="statistiques" cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key column="ID_INSTANCE"></key>
        <one-to-many class="Statistique" />
    </set>
        </class>
```

and the hbm file of class statistique is :

```
<class name="Statistique" table="STATISTIQUE">

    <id name="idStatistique" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="ID_STATISTIQUE"/>
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="tempsReponse" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="TEMPS_REPONSE"/>
    </property>

    <property name="date" type="timestamp">
        <column name="DATE"/>
    </property>

</class>
```

If the statistiques list is empty, this seems to be working fine. It fails with a foreign key violation error :

> Integrity constraint violation FKD18D3C4EDC6F4BFB table: STATISTIQUE in statement [delete from INSTANCE_Monitor where (ID_INSTANCE) IN (select ID_INSTANCE from HT_INSTANCE_Monitor)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a constraint in the database which demands for every row in statistique the existence of the row in instance_monitor. Before you can delete rows in instance_monitor, you have to delete the appertaining rows in statistique.

The clause `cascade="all"` does not imply a cascade delete on database level. It just forces hibernate to generate explicit delete statements for the child table (`statistique` in your case). The problem is, the delete statements may arrive in an order which is not compatible with your database constraint. This also can happen due to hibernate's re-ordering of database statements.

What you can do: Either remove the database constraint (if possible) or

1. Delete the rows from the statistique table, which belong to the instance_monitor "manually ("i. e. with separate delete statements)
2. Call session.flush() (prevents against the statement re-ordering by hibernate)
3. delete the instance_monitor

Answer (score 0):

> If the statistiques list is empty, this seems to be working fine. It
>   fails with a foreign key violation error :

You seem to have not enabled cascade delete at database level.

Comment: How to do it with hibernate beacause im genereting the database using SchemaExport

Comment: sorry was busy with some other things. I tried to find cascade delete configuration for hibernate but I am not completely aware how to do it. Probably this link might help -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209965/hibernate-ondelete-cascade-same-table

Comment: i didnt find the solution , im using cascade="all" that mean = on save-upadate and delete but i dont know why it's not working !!

Comment: just check the ddl of database table generated.. is it having the new cascade constraint?

Comment: i checked and he don't contain the the cascade constraint !! im using hibernate 3.2.6 and Mysql Innodb